# What fields can I update in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a SQL script I can run in Oracle that will tell me which fields I have permission to Update?

---

EDIT:

I've tried these

```
select * from USER_COL_PRIVS_RECD
select * from DBA_COL_PRIVS
select * from USER_COL_PRIVS_MADE
select * from ALL_TAB_PRIVS_MADE

select * from ALL_TAB_PRIVS_RECD
```

and the only one that has results is the last one which shows table permissions but not column permissions.

Comment: If you don't have specific column level privileges, then the table level privileges will apply.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a script to do this but you should be able to get your column level privileges from the USER COL PRIVS_RECD view. This site has more info:  [Oracle Column Level Privileges](http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/column_privileges.htm)